# SPFX Package always referring content or resources from localhost instead from CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

[image: When I tried to deploy the package in sharepoint everytime it refers to the localhost resources]

**Can someone please let me know from where I can change this configuration so that it should refer from the CDN path instead of localhost**

**Below is my package-solution.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "mega-menu-sp-fx-client-side-solution",
    "id": "8f49d75c-5a49-4657-b81b-0290f239350f",
    "version": "10.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "skipFeatureDeployment": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "features": [
      {
        "title": "Application Extension - Deployment of custom action.",
        "description": "Deploys a custom action with ClientSideComponentId association",
        "id": "0d2345df-2a49-4ce9-ba2d-bee7ad3e7a02",
        "version": "10.0.0.0",
        "assets": {
          "elementManifests": [
            "elements.xml",
            "clientsideinstance.xml"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/mega-menu-sp-fx.sppkg"
  }
}
```

**Below is my write-manifest.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
  "cdnBasePath": "https://Mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTechTheme/MenuFiles"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to figure out whats the issue. For publishing instead of gulp package-solution --ship  I had used  gulp package-solution  so unless and until we don't mention --ship it wont take the references for CDN

So for deploying the package in SPO we need to use   gulp bundle --ship  and  gulp package-solution --ship

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-sharepoint-library/), to load SPFx assets from a CDN or SharePoint library, set the value of `"includeClientSideAssets"` to `false`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    ...
    "includeClientSideAssets": false,
    ...
  }
}
```